# How can I easily move all the text in this csv file to the beginning of the line?

Tags: linux, awk, csv

I am new to Linux and also manipulating csv files. I am trying to figure out how to easily move this large column of text to the beginning of the line to where there are no spaces before the digits. Here's a small snippet of the file.Thanks!

#notice the spaces before:

```
    6 0.5
    24 0.67
    4 1
    12 2
```

Comment: Indeed, the awk advice I passed along yesterday ought to be applicable here @Tyler.

Comment: Ahh I see that I added the wrong values. There are two columns and the awk '{print $1  }' statement doesn't work as is. I do see that I can separate each column separately, I was just looking for a command to snap everything to the beginning of the line.

Comment: Hey @jsotola, I am using a data visualization tool called Termgraph that makes simple charts in the command line and the format requires no leading spaces.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9175801/how-to-remove-leading-and-trailing-whitespaces#9177838

Comment: please could you insert also the output you want?

Comment: Termgraph takes the two columns and makes a bar-chart with this format, I can only add one line of output here because of the formatting issue here:                               
                                                                                                                                     6  : ▇▇ 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`:

```bsh
sed 's/^[[:blank:]]*//' file >newfile
```

This would match and remove any sequence of blanks (spaces or tabs) at the start of any line in the file called `file`.  It would then write the resulting data to the file `newfile` by means of a redirection in the shell.